# Jenkins get environment variable with Environment Injector from property file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I want use variable from .property file
i defined this file in Build Environment -> Inject environment variables to the build process ->    Properties File Path, path: app/jenkins.properties
and Build -> Inject environment variables -> Properties File Path,
path: app/jenkins.properties
in the conditional step (single), use my variable COMMIT_COUNT from file this

```
waycurl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
 --data '{"data": {"BuildNumber":"'$COMMIT_COUNT'"}}
```

but instead of value, i get: BuildNumber: ${COMMIT_COUNT}